# Identity Matrix Question

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be a $n$ by $n$ matrix such that $A^2=I, B^2=I$ and $(AB)^2=I$. Prove that $AB = BA.$

Any hints on how to attempt this question? I'm stuck. But my first approach would be,

$A^2B^2=I * I$

$(AB)^2=I$

We cannot square root both sides because we are not dealing with real numbers? How would I approach this question?

Any hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

$(AB)^2=ABAB=I\tag 1$

Multipling $1$ by $A$ from the left and $B$ from the right we have,

$A^2BAB^2=AB\Rightarrow IBAI=AB\Rightarrow BA=AB$

Comment: Thank you I didn't see that. Cheers.

Comment: You are welcome.....It is a pleasure to have helped you. @Booby

Comment: I'm still getting use to the idea of matrices being different from the usual real number properties. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it needs some time to get used to it.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A^2=I$ and $B^2=I$ then $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices and
$$A^{-1}=A\quad;\quad B^{-1}=B$$
hence $$(AB)^2=ABAB=I\iff AB=B^{-1}A^{-1}=BA$$

Comment: You're welcome.